# Crash after java 32->64Bit using ole control site. EventHandler is no longer working properly

Tags: java, c#, swt, ole, eventhandler

Adding eventlistener to OLE controlsite in java.

### eventhandler object in C# dll is null, as a consequence, handleEvent(OleEvent e) is never called

I have read something about ole using int on 32Bit  and long on 64 Bit.
As I am Java dev and am "afraid" of COM dll and and things like ole, my options are limited here.
I also read somewhere that there is no true x64 mode for swt.ole. package in java. There is only compatibility mode..

Java:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleAutomation;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleControlSite;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleFrame;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.Variant;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
...
final Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
this.frame = new OleFrame(shell, 0);
try {
  this.controlSite = new OleControlSite(this.frame, 13374711, progID);
  automation = new OleAutomation(controlSite);
}
...
this.controlSite.addEventListener(1, listener);
```

---

C#:
    Event 1 with one argument int
    Event 2 with two arguments int, xml

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler();
public delegate void MyEventWithArgsHandler(Object sender, MyEventArgs e);

[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[Guid("69BFC529-1DED-450a-AB03-7DA067555914")]
public interface IDotNetViewer
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void MyEvent();
    [DispId(2)]
    void MyEventWithArgs(Object sender, MyEventArgs e);

}

public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
public event MyEventWithArgsHandler MyEventWithArgs;
```

Actually window opens normally, everything works fine. 
Closing the window (X in the upper corner) -> window goes empty, but stays open with not ending loading animation. Whole java application freezes.

How should the Dispatchinterface in C# look like?
Is it necessary to manipulate libraries?
I cannot find any problems on Java side. Java -> C# = good. C#->Java = not good.

Workarounds are also welcome :)

Comment: If you wrap code in a Using then when you exit the using everything would be disposed and the java and window should close.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input. I will follow this approach and report the outcome.